# Forwarding Attribute value from jsp to java

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have the below `action mappings` in the struts-config.xml file.

```
  <action path="/getTareWeight" 
  type="com.astrazeneca.usbod.scale.actions.GetTareByBarcodeAction"  
  name ="getTareByBarcodeForm" 
  scope="request" 
  validate="true" 
  input="/jsp/getTareByBarcode.jsp">

    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/tareWeightResult.jsp" />
    <forward name="failure" path="/jsp/tareWeight.jsp" />
  </action>


  <action path ="/ExportToExcel"
        type="com.astrazeneca.usbod.scale.actions.ExportTareToExcelAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/tareWeightResult.jsp"/>
    <forward name="failure" path="/jsp/tareWeight.jsp" />
  </action>
```

`GetTareByBarcodeAction` actually sets an attribute as below.

```
   request.getSession().setAttribute("TAREWEIGHT", tareWeightList);
```

tareWeightResult.jsp displays the contents of attribute `TAREWEIGHT`. Now, am placing a button in the `tareWeightResult.jsp`, which when clicked the contents of attribute `TAREWEIGHT` should be sent to a action form as below,

```
   <html:link forward="exportToExcel">Excel</html:link>
```

And in the ExportTareToExcelAction.java file, I have the following piece of code,

```
   List tareWeights = (List) request.getSession().getAttribute("TAREWEIGHT");
```

Here I could not get the attribute. Its returning null value to the List `tareWeights`.

Please let me know what should be done to retrieve the attibute contents in `ExportTareToExcelAction.java` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the session attribute is null, there are five possibilities:

- you stored null in the attribute
- the session has timed out because you didn't browse any page of the application for some time before clicking your export link
- you invalidated the session before clicking the export link
- you didn't use the same browser to get the tare weights and to export them
- something else modified the session (e.g., filter, different action, etc.)